# What will be the relative path from absolute path?

Tags: path, relative-path

Can anyone please tell me what will be the relative path name of `C:\\Users\\Kanav Mahajan\\Desktop\\A3 Assignment\\KanavMahajan_200419307.txt` of this absolute path ?

Comment: Realtive to what folder?

Comment: A3 Assignment folder

Comment: Your file is in the `A3 Assignment` folder, so the relative path is just the name of the text file.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute name is

```
C:\\Users\\Kanav Mahajan\\Desktop\\A3 Assignment\\KanavMahajan_200419307.txt
```

You are inside the `A3 Assignment` directory. Therefore, the absolute name of your current directory is

```
C:\\Users\\Kanav Mahajan\\Desktop\\A3 Assignment
```

Simply 'substract' one from the other to find the relative path

```
KanavMahajan_200419307.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Sir, relative path means the path relative to a specific folder or a script
so id your script is in 
`C:\Users\Kanav Mahajan\Desktop\A3 Assignment\`
and you want the relative path to the `KanavMahajan_200419307.txt` file
then , it will be just:
`KanavMahajan_200419307.txt`